# Multiple comparisons of two proportions prop.test

Tags: r

I have a large number of treatment and control groups I need to provide a comparison of population proportions for. I'm looking for a way to loop through a data.frame providing the test against each of the categories.

Sample data:

```
test_data <-  data.frame(
Category = c("A","A","B","B"),
Churn = c(56,46,83,58),
Other = c(180,555,144,86))
```

For example, compare category A (56/180 to 46/555) and so forth.

My initial solution:

```
by(test_data, test_data$Category, 
function(x) prop.test(test_data$Churn, test_data$Other))
```

The problem: The solution outputs by category but provides a 4 sample test instead of a two sample test. I've found lots of solutions that iterate well through rows but not so much by a category. Output as a list is fine for now.

Really appreciate the help on this one!

Comment: Could this help in any way? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/961/statistical-test-for-n-x-m-contingency-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `by()` function is incorrect. You are not using the `x` value that is passed in. By using the original variable name (`test_data`) no data is being subset for each `by()` call. Try

```
by(test_data, test_data$Category, 
function(x) prop.test(x$Churn, x$Other))
```